# Is there a clean way to look at a website's JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out and there are times where I see a website's function/interaction and I'd really like to read/learn the code they used to better understand how something was done. I know there's view pagesource but it's a mess and Inspect Element is really on the HTML/CSS.

Comment: If the JS is minfied, Chrome has a formatter function in the developer tools; although obviously that can't fix minfied names.

Comment: What do you mean by a "clean way"? Have you looked at the DevTools in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Inspect Element is *one component* of the devtools.  There are other tabs in the dev tools, such as the Debugger and Sources tabs.  Have you looked at them?

Comment: Hmm... It depends... But nowadays ja-files usually come compressed and are possibly precompiled from other languages like typescript. If I see some ui effect I want to emulate I usually try to find an open source project that does something similar where I can take a look how they accomplished it.

Comment: For any modern website, this will always be a mess. Typically, it's emitted js from typescript/babel, minified/obfuscated, the result of e.g. a react/angular/vue build process, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tool at this website, which you can use to turn ugly minified JS code into a beautiful source to read: 
https://html-cleaner.com/js/

Answer (score 0):

JS is often minified making it a mess but you can use browser developer tools to prettify it. How you can do it depends on your browser. In Firefox it is an icon in Debugger under the code view. There is no way to fix minified names like Carcigenicate commented but if it's open source library like jQuery you can find the source from their git repo.